# Evaluating the limit of the given integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Evaluate the following:
>   $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \displaystyle\int_0^\infty \dfrac{n\sin x}{1+n^2x^2}\ dx$

Attempt: My idea to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem. It can easily be shown that $f_n(x)=\dfrac{n\sin x}{1+n^2x^2}$ converges pointwise to $0$ on $\left(0,\infty\right)$ but I'm having difficulties on trying to get an integrable function $g$ that would satisfy $|f_n|\leq g$. I tried using the inequalities $|\sin t|\leq t$ for small $t$ and of course the obvious one which is $|\sin t|\leq 1$ but the function I get is not integrable. Any help would be great.

Comment: *Hint.* Substitute $u = nx$.

Comment: Hint, use $u=nx$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $u=nx$, then your integral becomes
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin\frac{u}{n}}{1+u^2}\ du
\end{align}

Comment: Oh thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

*Just added for your curiosity.*

We can compute the antiderivative, starting with
$$\frac n {1+n^2x^2}=\frac n {(nx-i)(nx+i)}=\frac {ni}  2 \left(\frac 1 {nx+i}-\frac 1 {nx-i} \right)$$ which make that we face the problem of
$$I=\int \frac{\sin(x)}{x+a}\,dx$$ Let $x+a=t$ to make
$$I=\int \frac{\sin(t-a)}{t}\,dt=\cos(a)\int \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\,dt-\sin(a)\int \frac{\cos(t)}{t}\,dt $$ that is to say
$$I=\cos (a)\, \text{Si}(t)-\sin (a) \,\text{Ci}(t)$$ where appear [the sine and cosine integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral) (don' worry : sooner or later, you will leran about them).

Using the integration bounds and then the asymptotics, you will end with
$$I_n=\int_0^\infty \dfrac{n\sin x}{1+n^2x^2}\, dx=\frac{\log \left({n}\right)-\gamma +1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ which, for sure, shows the limit but also how it is approached. Moreover, as shown in the table below, this gives an approximation of the result
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0.422784 & 0.646761 \\
 2 & 0.557966 & 0.599204 \\
 3 & 0.507132 & 0.521764 \\
 4 & 0.452270 & 0.459176 \\
 5 & 0.406444 & 0.410274 \\
 6 & 0.369091 & 0.371446 \\
 7 & 0.338385 & 0.339943 \\
 8 & 0.312778 & 0.313865 \\
 9 & 0.291112 & 0.291902 \\
 10 & 0.272537 & 0.273130 \\
 20 & 0.170926 & 0.171014 \\
 30 & 0.127466 & 0.127495 \\
 40 & 0.102792 & 0.102804 \\
 50 & 0.086696 & 0.086703 \\
 60 & 0.075286 & 0.075290 \\
 70 & 0.066733 & 0.066735 \\
 80 & 0.060060  & 0.060062 \\
 90  & 0.054696 & 0.054697 \\
 100 & 0.050280 & 0.050281
\end{array}
\right)$$